# How to do pagination for chat app messages

Tags: django, postgresql, chat

I am trying to build a real time chat application.
What it needs to do:

- allow users to send messages to other users inside a 'chat' similar to private chat on apps like whatsapp and messenger.
- after a user sends a message to a chat the other user needs to receive it instantly by having their chat data updated.

What I would like to know is how to handle pagination with this type of problem.

If a user scrolls up and tries to get their old chat data (message history) I can do pagination on the database, however, if the other user in the chat sends a message i.e. adds a new message to the database for that chat, this instantly offsets the whole chat history/pagination by one (one for every message sent). This of course would result in duplicate messages. And visa versa, if the other user deletes a message then our chat history pagination will be returning missing results. Of course this only occurs if our user is scrolling for chat history while the other user is posting/deleting message.

Currently I am considering doing this by asking for the last  of results before or equal to the datetime to nearest nano seconds of the oldest message on client side. Then, after receiving the data, check if the first message (the most recent message in the new paged chat history) id of the new data (chat history) is the same as
the newest data (client side) and pop it off (this should always be the case? I think???). This to me seems like a hack. Please correct me if I am wrong.

The backend I am using is Postgres wrapped with django. Django does not offer a solution for this other than the pagination postgres wrapper. I was also looking for something that would do this by id. i.e. I could go to the database and be like: 'yo postgres, give me 30 results ordered by datetime, but only return the ones before the id 459432...and some other stuff.'

I could also do this by fetching the whole chat history of a given chat and implementing what I just said above, but at that point I may as well store the whole lot client side and let the client app deal with rendering and storing it. As this is a small app, it is unlikely message histories will be tens of thousands messages long...but who knows. I don't trust users not to sit there spamming messages.

Comment: Have you find out the way? I am curious too

Comment: I went with what I suggested (hacky way)

Answer (score 4):

Since it's a chat log, you know for sure no older messages will suddenly appear. All you need to do is make sure that when loading older messages, new messages don't change the starting point of your pagination.

On the client, when you first open the chat window, store the current time as your "paging cutoff time". When querying the database for a particular page, discard all messages newer than the "paging cutoff time" before doing your skip/take.

You might run into problems when deleting messages depending on your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [CursorPagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#cursorpagination)

> Provides a consistent pagination view. When used properly CursorPagination ensures that the client will never see the same item twice when paging through records, even when new items are being inserted by other clients during the pagination process.